# Testing in-app purchase managed product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to test a managed product in my application. When i want to add a managed product in developer console, it asks for price. I can't set it to 0.00. I don't want to pay for it when I want to test my application.

Is there a way to test managed products? I tried "android.test.purchased", but it is not restored with restore transaction..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I found was to set the item to the minimum price and actually buy it for real.

When you have finished testing, you can refund it. If you refund within the first hour or so, it will never be charged to your card anyway.

Comment: Right, if you cancel the order before it's charged, it never gets to your card. If you refund after it's charged, you lose the 30% Google fee.

Comment: No, the fee is reversed too. You don't lose anything.

Comment: Unless that has changed lately, this has not been my experience. If you refund the user gets their money back, Google gets 30% of the price, and your -30%. Maybe it's different for IAB test accounts?

Comment: I only did it this week. £1 item was charged and refunded £1. My checkout balance was reduced by £0.70 (customer is refunded the whole amount, 70% of that amount comes from your checkout balance, 30% comes from google)